# Disable Google Chrome Autonaming (1) on downloads

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extensions, rename

Please tell me the way, how can I disable the google chrome auto naming behaviour.
The a filename is exist in the actual folder, then Chrome says default name: filename (1).txt

This is not good for me, is there anybody who knows the way of disable this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not supported. As of 08/2020, and presumably now, there is no ability to disable Chrome's "Autonaming (*n*) on downloads" .

[David, Platinum Product Expert 2011 (not a Google employee)](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/62131910?hl=en&msgid=62306880):

> This option doesn't exist today I'm afraid. If this is important to you, I’d encourage you to also send this feedback to Google.

Answer (score 2):

You can set it to open a dialogue so that you can change the name and location of each file you download.

1. Open the Settings page (type "chrome://settings/" in the address bar)
2. Click "Show advanced settings..." at the bottom of the page
3. Tick the box next to "Ask where to save each file before downloading"

[image]

Comment: This is not answer for the question :)

Comment: Then I don't understand the question. Which function are you trying to disable? Do you want it to handle duplicate files names differently?

Comment: If ihave a file in the given folder named "test.txt", and I would save into that folder ('save as' opens the last location what is good), the same file again. The browser try to adds name as "test (1).txt"
The desired name would be again "test.txt", and then prompt name exist, overwrite...